# Programmatically-created UIButton doesn't respond

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm programmatically creating two `UIButtons` as subviews of two separate `UIViews` that comprise an animated bar chart. The chart is driven by calculated values. At the end of the animation, each button appears at the top of its respective bar. Looks like this:

[image]

The purpose of the button (indicated by the black marquee in the screenshot) is to display information and, when tapped, segue to a detail view controller, where additional information is presented in a tableview.

I want to change the color of the title text on the button according to it's control state, so that when it's tapped it changes color to indicate selection. The initial symptom in my problem was that the text color didn't change when tapped.

So I made a little test app to compare the behavior of a programmatically-created `UIButton` in a different setting. The button creation and implementation code for the test app is essentially identical to that in the original app, minus the arithmetic. My observation is that it seems to work fine in the test app.

My subsequent testing indicates that the buttons in the original app simply don't respond at all. Like dead things.

Here's the relevant code from the original project. I apologize for the length, and I'm well aware that SO is not a proof-reading service, but I'm just plain lost as to what the problem might be:

```
-(void) makeBarChart
{
    RiserBar *thisRiser;
    firstLabel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    secondLabel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // Bar colors

    UIColor *startColor1;
    UIColor *endColor1;
    UIColor *startColor2;
    UIColor *endColor2;

    if (goButtonKey == 1)
    {
        startColor1 = [UIColor blackColor];
        endColor1 = [UIColor redColor];
        startColor2 = [UIColor blackColor];
        endColor2 = [UIColor blueColor];
    }

    else if (goButtonKey == 2)
    {
        startColor1 = [UIColor blackColor];
        endColor1 = Rgb2UIColor(253, 165, 1);
        startColor2 = [UIColor blackColor];
        endColor2 = Rgb2UIColor(26, 138, 1);
    }
    else if (goButtonKey == 0)
    {
        startColor1 = [UIColor blackColor];
        endColor1 = [UIColor greenColor];
        startColor2 = [UIColor blackColor];
        endColor2 = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

// Here's the entry point if I have more than 2 risers

for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    thisRiser = [[RiserBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    thisRiser.tag = i+1;
    [self.chartView addSubview:thisRiser];
}

    // Calculate final dimensions of risers
int barWidth = self.chartView.bounds.size.width /((2 * 2) -1);
int focusBarEndHeight = (self.chartView.bounds.size.height-80) * (focusItemPercent / 100);
int benchmarkBarEndHeight = (self.chartView.bounds.size.height-80) * (benchmarkItemPercent / 100);



for (thisRiser in self.chartView.subviews)
{
    switch (thisRiser.tag)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            [thisRiser addSubview:firstLabel];
            [firstLabel setHidden:YES];


            [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                  delay:.2
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^
             {
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(35, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, 0);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = startColor1;
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(35, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, -focusBarEndHeight);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = endColor1;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:thisRiser.bounds].CGPath;
             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {
                 firstLabel.frame = CGRectMake(thisRiser.bounds.origin.x, thisRiser.frame.size.height -focusBarEndHeight - 55, barWidth, 60);
                 [firstLabel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
                 firstLabel.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                 firstLabel.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                 [firstLabel setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%.2f%%\nTime--%@",focusItemName,focusItemPercent,actualDurationFocusItem] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                 [firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 [firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                 [firstLabel setHidden:NO];
                 [firstLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(firstLabelAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                 [firstLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                 [thisRiser setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


                 NSLog(@"Done!");
             }];
        }
            break;

        case 2:

        {
            [thisRiser addSubview:secondLabel];
            [secondLabel setHidden:YES];


            [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                  delay:.2
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^
             {
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(barWidth + 70, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, 0);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = startColor2;
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(barWidth + 70, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, -benchmarkBarEndHeight);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = endColor2;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:thisRiser.bounds].CGPath;

             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {
                 secondLabel.frame = CGRectMake(thisRiser.bounds.origin.x, thisRiser.frame.size.height -benchmarkBarEndHeight - 55, barWidth, 60);
                 [secondLabel setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%.2f%%\nTime--%@",benchmarkItemName,benchmarkItemPercent,actualDurationBenchmarkItem] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 [secondLabel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
                 secondLabel.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                 secondLabel.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                 [secondLabel setHidden:NO];
                 secondLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                 [secondLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 [secondLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                 [secondLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(secondLabelAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                 [secondLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                 [thisRiser setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


                 NSLog(@"Done!");
             }];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}

-(IBAction)firstLabelAction:(UIButton*)sender

{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"activityDetailPush" sender:firstLabel];
}


-(void) secondLabelAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"categoryDetailPush" sender:secondLabel];
}
```

Thanks for looking. All help appreciated!

Comment: You're duplicating your own question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621643/conundrum-with-uibutton-uicontrolstateselected-text-wont-change-colors) Please modify the original question rather than having two identical questions open. Thanks! You might simply delete the other question.

Comment: It looks like your buttons are outside the bounds of their superview, which will cause them to be unresponsive.

Comment: I'll delete the other one, @matt--thanks. Was unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @rdelmar--you nailed it! It's out of bounds of the superview. It works if I place it inside the super. There are other issues that came to light once I moved it, but at least it's responsive. Of course, now I have to figure out how to place it in it's current position (which is relative to the riser bar), but is a subview of the chartView, which is the area behind the risers. If you'll put your comment in an answer, I'll be happy to accept and upvote it. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can solve it.

```
UIButton *firstLabel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
firstLabel.frame = CGRectZero;
UIButton *secondLabel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
secondLabel.frame = CGRectZero;
```

Comment: the two buttons did not define button type?

Comment: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect no longer exists. He's using UIButtonTypeCustom, and rightly so.

Comment: @matt he's using `initWithFrame:`.  Buttons should always be created with `buttonWithType:`

Comment: Is there something that happens with CGRectZero that I'm unaware of for buttons.  It seems like setting a frame to zeros would make it not appear at all.

Comment: @Logan look at the OP's original question: he sets the frame correctly later on. Confusing, I know.

Comment: Okay, so @Bibo you should be using UIButtonTypeCustom, since that is what the OP wants. You might change your answer to that, and let's see then if it solves his issue!

Comment: @Bibo He does it correctly in his other version of the same question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638918/programmatically-created-uibutton-doesnt-respond

Comment: As @matt points out, they were correctly created as `UIButtonTypeCustom` previously. I was getting kind of desperate and tried this route. However, the buttons don't work either way.

Comment: Please see @rdelmar's comment above. The problem was that the button is out of the bounds of its superview. Thanks for taking the time to look at the code and comment!